# My android studio code is underlined all red

Tags: java, android

All code in all of my android studio is all red. I think jdk is not being recognized. I recently(yesterday) updated the android studio version from 3.6X to 4.0. I did have a popup about some plugins like json viewer etc

- It is not recognizing the jdk. if i select any jdk it still doesnt work
- File > settings. menu does NOT open
- Already reinstalled fresh android studio but still same problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. I had to come out of the project and on the start screen where there are list of all projects there was red exclamation mark in red which I clicked and it showed csv plugin which was causing errors in ide. i disabled that and restarted and all fixed.